# How can I force Laravel to use a different mysql database?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running a Laravel 5.2 app on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu. For some reason the app is telling me I'm using a database other then what I've defined on the `env` file. My `.env` file is as such:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=snipsnip
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=paidfor
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=paidfor
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=snipsnip

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

But the application is throwing the error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'phpmyadmin.products_list`

I've ran

```
php artisan optimize
```

which yield *Generating optimized class loader* and then I ran

```
php artisan migrate
```

which resulted in *Nothing to migrate*.

I've several databases on MySQL server as listed below and I want the application to use the database `paidfor` and not `phpmyadmin`.

```
information_schema
mysql
paidfor
performance_schema
phpmyadmin
```

How can I fix this issue?

```
  MySqlConnection {#148 ▼
  #pdo: PDO {#158 ▶}
  #readPdo: null
  #reconnector: Closure {#153 ▶}
  #queryGrammar: MySqlGrammar {#147 ▶}
  #schemaGrammar: null
  #postProcessor: MySqlProcessor {#151}
  #events: Dispatcher {#5 ▶}
  #fetchMode: 8
  #fetchArgument: null
  #fetchConstructorArgument: []
  #transactions: 0
  #queryLog: []
  #loggingQueries: false
  #pretending: false
  #database: "phpmyadmin"
  #doctrineConnection: null
  #tablePrefix: ""
  #config: array:12 [▼
    "driver" => "mysql"
    "host" => "127.0.0.1"
    "port" => "3306"
    "database" => "phpmyadmin"
    "username" => "phpmyadmin"
    "password" => "snipsnip"
    "charset" => "utf8"
    "collation" => "utf8_unicode_ci"
    "prefix" => ""
    "strict" => false
    "engine" => null
    "name" => "mysql"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. phpMyAdmin is a software that is used to manage a MySQL database, it is not a database in itself.
Based on the informations you're providing, laravel is already using the paidfor database. Just check if the tables are indeed in the DB.

Comment: @AntoineB inside the phpmyadmin interface, there is a database called phpmyadmin that was created when I installed phpmyadmin.

Comment: Well, based on my understanding of your question, you're already using the "paidfor" database.

Comment: I wish that was the case because when I try to pull info from the `paidfor` database I get `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'phpmyadmin.products_list`. It's still looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you sure the file you're editing is `.env` and not `.not.example` ?

Comment: @AntoineB 1000% positive. `.env` is the only file in my laravel directory. Thank you for working through this with me. I'm steadily collecting downvotes lol

Comment: Well, you're getting downvoted because people don't understand that phpmyadmin is indeed a database and not the software. You should clarify this in your question and in the title.

Comment: it's been updated!

Comment: Open `public/index.php` and just before `$response->send()` write `dd(\DB::connection());` and post the resulting object (including the property `config`) on your question.

Comment: @milz done! I see the phpmyadmin part now. I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Let's [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113354/37533331)...

Answer (score 1):

If you updated the `.env` file and ran `php artisan optimize` and it still doesn't work, then there's one of two things that could happen:

1. You're not using the values of `.env` for the database connection.

   Open the file `config/database.php` and look for the `connections` key. Verify that you're using the values of env on the connection name (in your case `mysql`). You should have something like:

   ```
   'mysql' => [
       'driver' => 'mysql',
       'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
       'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
       'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
       'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
       'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
       'charset' => 'utf8',
       'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
       'prefix' => '',
       'strict' => false,
       'engine' => null,
   ],
   ```
2. Your model is using another connection rather than `mysql`. Check the model for something like

   ```
    $this->connection = 'other-connection-name';
   ```

   or something like

   ```
   $this->setConnection('other-connection-name');
   ```

Comment: When you say, "check the model", where exactly am I supposed to be checking? The model I am using only contains `protected $table = 'offer_codes';`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use `paidfor` database in your system, and access from phpmyadmin, create a new user for application with these privileges: `ALTER, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE` (you could, also, create two users, one for migrations only and other for application).

With you root user, run in your PhpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'myhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON paidfor TO 'myuser'@'myhost';
```

After that, use your new user in your `.env` file.

Then when you access PhpMyAdmin, with your new user, you will have access only to this database.

**Don't ever never ever use root user in your application**

Comment: Root has "too much access". He's trying to log in paidfor database, but root user has other or none default database. Doing this, the new user will access only paidfor, as default, and the application will be more secure.

Comment: Yet, this is not the problem, you can definitely access your laravel database with the root user. This is not an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could not be found with the instance I was running because the server was ignoring the `.emv` file. The only workaround I could figure out was to boot up a brand new EC2 instance, reinstall Composer, Laravel, and try again.

Special thanks to @milz for spending about 2 hours working through this with me!